# Example of Approximately Inner automorphism which is not inner

Tags: c-star-algebras

Apart from inductive limit constructions such as the Carr Algebra (Where you could just take direct sums of unitaries) I can't think of an example of a C*-algebra and an approximately inner automorphism of it which is not inner. I was wondering if any of you knows an example of such.